# Is there a setting on the Panasonic Lumix FZ48 which would lock the buttons from working?

Tags: camera-settings, camera-controls

I recently purchased a mint condition Panasonic Lumix FZ48, it takes pictures and for the first 20 minutes or so all the functions worked but then all the other buttons stopped working, I can't access the menu to reset the camera. I am unaware if the device is actually broken or if I have engaged a setting that only allows the shutter button to be used. Any help with this issue us is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the battery for an extended period? Sometimes this will allow the camera to reset even if turning the camera off and back on will not.

Comment: That may have actually worked, to let the internal solid state memory's battery run dry, unfortunately i have returned the camera now but i accept that this probably would have worked. Thank you